# Merging lists in a single pySpark dataframe

Tags: python, list, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am going through the pySpark 1.6.2 documentation in order to merge my data into a single dataframe.

I have a list of 19 items (listname:sizes):

```
[9, 78, 13, 3, 57, 60, 66, 32, 24, 1, 2, 15, 2, 2, 76, 79, 100, 73, 4]
```

and a 2D list containing 19 not same length sub-lists (listname:data):

```
[[a,b,c],[d,e,f,g,h,i,j].......[x,y,z,a,f]]
```

I am trying to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        name                   size
0     [a,b,c]                  9
1     [d,e,f,g,h,i,j]          78
2     ........                 ...
.     ........                 ...
.     ........                 ...
18    [x,y,z,a,f]              4
```

But I can't figure out a way to do that.

I have already iterated through the list and I could append the two columns after each iteration.
But I am finding it hard to find a way to create a Dataframe and fill it step by step.

This is my code:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True), StructField("size", IntegerType(), True)])
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame([],schema)

for i in range(len(data)):
    sizes.append(len(data[i]))
    t = sqlContext.DataFrame([[data[i], sizes[i]]],
                         columns=['name', 'size'])
    dataframe = dataframe.append(t, ignore_index=True)

dataframe.show()
```

but it returns me this:

```
+----+----+
|name|size|
+----+----+
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this using the zip() function. If you do:

```
t = zip(data, sizes)
```

You will have a list of tuples, one for each pair:

```
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], 9),
 (['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], 78),
  ...
 (['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'f'], 4)]
```

Now you just have to create the DataFrame using the list of tuples:

```
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(t,schema)
```